# Control from window1 to window 2

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a `Window1` which has two `ListView` Boxes namely `ListView_Category` and `ListView_FilesInCategory`. On the basis of selection in `ListView_Category`, `ListView_FilesInCategory` gets populated.

Now, as per the selection from `ListView_FilesInCategory`, a new window, `Window2`, opens in which the file details are shown. I am opening this new window from the `SelectionChanged` event of `ListView_FilesInCategory` by making the object of `Window2`'s class and by passing values from `Window1` to `Window2` through the parameterized constructor of `Window2`, that is, by passing the values while I am creating the object.

Now, my problem is that when I am closing `Window2`, and then when I change selection of `ListView_Category` box, then the `ListView_FilesInCategory` doesn't get populated. Although the correct values are being fetched from the server, which I am checking by printing them on the screen just before the following command, but still this command is not being executed and my `ListView_FilesInCategory` box remains unchanged.

```
ListView_FilesInCategories.Items.Add(elem.Value);
```

Kindly help.

This is the piece of code where I am populating the `ListView_FilesInCategories` box:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(
                (Action)(() =>
                {

                    //ListView_FilesInCategories.Items.Clear();
                    //key = (ListView_Categories.SelectedItem).ToString();

                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlf);
                    List<String> files = new List<String>();
                    var q = (dynamic)null;
                    q = from x in doc.Descendants("file") select x;

                    foreach (var elem in q)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("egnren"+elem.Value);
                        //MessageBox.Show(elem.Value);
                        ListView_FilesInCategories.Items.Add(elem.Value);
                    }  
                }));
```

Is the problem being caused because I am using an action delegate here?

Answer (score 0):

Your using list. Instead of that use observablecollection

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I am new to WPF